# how can we highlight a long title?

Tags: color, highlighting, colorbox

I want to highlight my title with a certain color. My title is long and it lays in 3 lines. How can I create a colorbox for the title? \title{My Desired Title} conflicts with the command \hl.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please provide a complete but minimal example which reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{color,graphicx,soul,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{\hl{Long Long Long Title  Long Long Long 
Title Long Long Long Title Long Long Long Title 
Long Long Long Title}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Giving you a title that is highlighted on several lines. Maybe I misunderstood your problem?

[image]